# What is wrong with my java code for calculating factorials?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, calculator, factorial

So I'm extremely new to java, just started today a couple of hours ago. And I have no idea what to do about this; so far my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Class_one{
static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] listArray;
    System.out.print("Please enter the number to calculate the factorial for: ");
    if (userInput.hasNextInt()){
        int numEnter = userInput.nextInt();
        final int numEnterC = numEnter;
        if (numEnter >= 0){
            listArray = new int[numEnterC];
            int arrayVal = 0;
            while (numEnter >= 0){
                listArray [arrayVal] = numEnter;
                arrayVal++;
                numEnter = numEnter - 1;
                if (numEnter == 0){
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (arrayVal >= -1){
                int newArVal = listArray[arrayVal]*listArray[arrayVal - 1];
                newArVal = listArray[arrayVal];
                arrayVal = arrayVal - 1;
            }
            //I don't know what's happening in the next line:
            String nArVals = Integer.toString(newArVal));
            System.out.println(nArVals + " is the result of the factorial operations of " + numEnterC);
        }
        if (numEnter == 0){
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        if (numEnter <= 0){
            System.out.println("Negatives unavailable for factorial.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? I don't want you guys to just paste the answer, I want to figure it out myself, so could you give me a hint, or not a direct answer for me to figure this out on my own?

Here's the error message I'm getting (I'm using Eclipse):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
newArVal cannot be resolved to a variable.
Syntax error on token ")", delete this token.
at project_one.Class_one.main(Class_one.java:27)
```

Comment: Where is your declaration for `newArVal`?

Comment: Isn't it already declared? Or do I have to declare every int like *int name of int;*?

Comment: Haha sorry, that was the hint. I'm not sure how I can hint more without outright stating the answer.

Comment: I see. Thank you! I'll see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create the array

```
int numEnter = userInput.nextInt();
int factorial = 1;
for (int i=1; i <= numEnter; i++) factorial *= i;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a poorly framed question.
2. I would implement totally differently in a recursive fashion

   ```
   public int factorial(int number){
       if(number>0){
           return number*factorial(number-1);
       } else {
       return 1;
       }
   }
   ```

I haven't run this.

Comment: Note, this answer does not handle improper input well

Comment: Recursive solutions should always be avoided in Java.

Comment: @mascoj Why? Broad-brush statements should be avoided everywhere. Give reasons. There is a large number of commonly encountered counter-examples.

Comment: You actually have to be careful with recursive functions. In some cases the computation might need too many recursive calls. But in this case, since you can have at least 256k stacks, and this a factorial function, you get an integer overflow way before you run out of stacks. So using recursion here is totally fine.

Comment: I would like to use `factorial(int number, int result)` which is a tail recursive call, but anyway JVM doesn't support tail-recursion optimization at current stage.

Comment: @MarioDekena Yes, which will cause an overflow exception which will have to propagate up the entire stack. It's better to avoid these cases all together.

Comment: @mascoj You are right. But keep in mind that the maximum number of recursive calls you can have with this function is 12, because 13! is allready bigger then Integer.MAX_VALUE. 13 stacks isnt too bad.

Answer (score 0):

The variable newArVals is not in scope when its referenced in the following line.

```
        String newArVals = Integer.toString(newArVal));
```

To bring it in scope you have to define newArVal  outside the while loop i.e.

```
     int newArVal =0; 
     while (arrayVal >= -1){
            newArVal = listArray[arrayVal]*listArray[arrayVal - 1];
            newArVal = listArray[arrayVal];
            arrayVal = arrayVal - 1;
        }
```